# Are supersets of measurable sets measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

[Challenging conventional wisdom question](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-%E2%80%93-and-answer-them/)

Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu) = (\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{M}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda)$, where $\mathscr{M}(\mathbb{R})$ is the collection of all $\lambda$-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

If $A \in \Sigma$ and $B \subseteq A$, it does not follow that $B \in \Sigma$.

However, if $C \supseteq A$, do we have $C \in \Sigma$?

I guess we can have $C = A \cup V$ where $V \notin \Sigma$ (eg Vitali set) and $V \subsetneq A$, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that *every* set is a superset of the empty set.

Comment: Hehehe thanks Cameron Buie ^-^